# Accessing SSRS on a local network - No Domain

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, reporting-services, windows-7

I'm having a small issue and starting to tear my hair out unfortunately.
Please excuse me if this has been answered before but I've been searching for two days and nothing is working.

I have 2 computers, one is windows 7 which is the "Server" ( 3 administrator accounts, A,B,C)
The other windows 8.1 we'll call this "Client" (1 admin account same name as C)

The Server is running MSSQL express - 2014 with SSRS on Acc:A. I'm using the BIDS (on the server Acc:B) to create reports and deploy them onto the report server happily.

What I am needing to do is to be able to access the reports from my client pc but I cant seem to be able to find what is restricting me from accessing the reports or accessing it as a service reference in VS2013.

When I Log onto accounts (useing RDP) B,C I can access the reports server happily but I try to access the reports server from the client using "Server\C" as windows login credentials  it says I don't have the privileges for the home page but I can access the Site Settings.

I have a nasty feeling this is all because I'm not running on a windows server environment with domains and such which I would rather not need to use till I deploy this (when I buy a proper server) as at the moment this is all trial and proof of concept stage.

Any help anyone can give would be absolutely amazing! Thanks

Comment: what do you mean with "I try to access the reports server from the client using "Server\C" as windows login credentials"? you try to open http://server/reports in IE, get a login prompt, log in with your server\adminC account, and then it fails?

Comment: Yeah unfortunately that's what happens when I am using my client pc. When I do it with my sever pc it doesn't even prompt for it and just goes straight through.

Comment: and on the server pc, you are logged as adminC and it works? just to check the permissions for adminC in SSRS are fine. usually your scenario should work (for the report manager website part)

Comment: Yeah it works fine to get to the home part and everything else when on the server and logged in as C, just when I use the Client and log in as Server/C I can only get access to the site settings. I'm going to try and connect to it from a different PC and log in as Server/C and see what happens.

Comment: Just tried it on 3 other PC's all trying to log in as Server/C and no joy all came up with no permissions.

Comment: can you be more specific about the error message you get? you say you can go into site settings, so part of the site opens?

Comment: It's a permissions error which is why i'm so confused as when i'm local to the Server it just goes through with no prompt!  "User 'Server/C' does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed."

Answer (score 1):

Finally managed to get it working after ages, it'll be different when I deploy it but, I simply disabled the ntlm authentication and went for windows basic authentication by doing step 4 in this documentation!

Thanks for all the help!

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8faf2938-b71b-4e61-a172-46da2209ff55(v=sql.110)